# Изменение свойств локального пользователя средством PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Написал скрипт на создание определенного количества пользователей, но не знаю как сделать следующее:

- Нужно прописать пользователям "среду" , чтобы при входе запускалась программа.
- На вкладке "Общие" проставить галочки "Запретить смену пароля пользователем" и "Срок действия пароля неограничен"

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот это:

```
$Comp = ([adsi]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME")
$UserToModify = $Comp.psbase.Children.Find("Гость")
$UserToModify.LoginScript = "c:\scripts\some_logon_script.ps1"  # Сценарий входа
$UserToModify.UserFlags = 64 -bor 65536   # Это флаги
$UserToModify.SetInfo()
```

В сценарии входа вы можете выполниить запуск необходимой пользователю программы и настройку «среды».

Более подробная информация про флаги настройки пользователей:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144

Comment: Прошу прощения, не указал что сервер без домена. Соответственно этот вариант не подходит. 

Нашел решение с галочками:
wmic useraccount where "name='$user'" set passwordexpires=false
wmic useraccount where "name='$user'" set passwordchangeable=false

$user - имя учетной записи

Вопрос по поводу среды остается открытым. Прописать Logon скриптом не вариант. Так как не всем пользователям это нужно. Локальную групповую политику применить на локальную группу нельзя.